# how to update data on button click in angular2?

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I have notificationService which contains data to be displayed in toast notification. Every element of data array contains data of a toast notification.

```
export Notification service {
    data:Array<NotificationData>;
    getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}

export class NotificationData {
     dismissed:boolean;
}
```

Now data array is being used in toast component.

```
 export class ToastNotificationComponent implements OnInit {
      data: Array<NotificationData>;
      constructor(public ns: NotificationService) { 
        this.data = ns.getData();
      }
    }
```

I want to update the dismissed variable on button click.

```
 <div class="toast-container">

      <div *ngFor = "let datum of data">
        <button (click)= "closeToast($event)" >close</button>
       </div>
    </div>
```

How can I bind the view with notificationData here?

If I use event binding I won't be able to access notificationData through DOM node.
Is there a solution using ngModel here?

Comment: kindly show your notificationData response or this.data response

Comment: it will contain some arrays, strings and numbers.    
   appType:string;
  timeString:string;
  severityLevel:number;
  objects: Array<ObjectType>;
  coordinates: Array<Coordinate>; 
  imgHeight: number;
  imgWidth: number;
  pointString: string;
  //Read or unread notification
  dismissed: boolean;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enter this:

   < button (click)= "data.dismissed = !data.dismissed " >close

Comment: Thank you. It was simple solution.